# Удалить изображение из cache

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Пишу приложение на ASP.NET Core, Vue.JS.
Создал обработчик изображения для аватара. Когда меняю аватар, обрезанное изображение сохраняется в тот же файл, ссылку на который использует изображение.
И в чем вопрос. Изображение сохраняется в cache. Получается, я не могу обновить его после редактирования аватара.

Можно ли на javascript отключить добавление данного изображения в cache?
Либо обновить его?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляйте к ссылке на картинку рандомный GET параметр и браузер будет думать, что это новая картинка.
Что-то типа такого:

```
<img src="images/avatar.jpg?321231321">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Именно этот вариант сработал.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста